# Presto Sandbox cluster on AWS EMR - add connector (catalog/.properties)

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr, presto

I just deployed a Presto Sandbox cluster on AWS using EMR. Is there any way to add connectors to my Presto cluster apart from manually (ssh) creating the properties and then restarting the cluster?

Comment: Found a clean way of doing this using AWS bootstrap actions: https://github.com/awslabs/emr-bootstrap-actions/tree/master/presto#presto-configuration--

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a UI to add a connector, Presto itself doesn't offer that and as far as I know Amazon EMR doesn't either. I'm afraid you'll have to add connectors manually by SSH-ing to the master node, creating the appropriate file, distributing it to all the nodes and then restarting everything.

Answer (score -1):

Adding connectors to Presto with EMR does require manual restarting as you mention. You might be able to use a CFT to automate some of this, or you can try something like Ahana Cloud https://ahana.io/ahana-cloud/ which is a managed serviced for Presto in AWS.

Comment: No it doesn't, connections can be added during bootstrap.